# DB2 Get latest modified and previous value from audit table

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a audit table, i am trying to get the current and previous value for a column(rank) with audit timestamp information. I would like to get the timestamp when the value was changed. E.g:
[image]

For `id = 1`, rank was latest changed `from 3 to 5` on `13-05-2021 14:10` by `userid = 2`.
I have written below query it gives the current and previous modified value but it gives the `latest date` and userid (`17-05-2021 20:00` and `2`), because row_number is ordered by timestamp.

```
with v_rank as (    
    select * from (
        select
            id,
            a.rank as current_rank,
            b.rank as previous_rank,
            a.log_timestamp,
            a.log_username,
            row_number() over(partition by a.id order by a.log_timestamp) as rnum
        from
            user a
            inner join user b on a.id = b.id and a.log_timestamp > b.timestamp
            where
                a.rank != b.rank
            order by a.log_timestamp, b.timestamp
    ) where rnum = 1
)
select * from v_rank
```

Any suggestion on how can i get the correct `timestamp(13-05-2021 14:10)` and `userid(2)`.
Edit:
Rank can also be null, in that case i need to get the blank in query result.

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: expected output is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `lag()` with filtering:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             lag(rank) over (partition by id order by log_timestamp) as prev_rank
      from user u
     ) u
where rank <> prev_rank;
```